# What is the difference between json() method and json.loads()

Tags: python, json, dictionary, python-requests

I was practicing python with json data. I came across .json() method and json.loads(). Both returned the same output.I was wondering if there is any difference between these two.

```
r = request.get('name of url')
text = r.text
data = json.loads(text)

r = request.get('name of url')
data1 = r.json()
```

Both data and data1 has a same type "dict" and returns the same output. Why should we use one vs other? Any insights is appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

The `json` method of `requests.models.Response` objects ends up calling the `json.loads` method, but it may do something more.

You can see in the [`requests.models.Response.json` source code](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/428f7a275914f60a8f1e76a7d69516d617433d30/requests/models.py#L894) that it sometimes tries to guess the encoding prior to calling `complexjson.loads` (which is in fact `json.loads`):

```
    if not self.encoding and self.content and len(self.content) > 3:
        # No encoding set. JSON RFC 4627 section 3 states we should expect
        # UTF-8, -16 or -32. Detect which one to use; If the detection or
        # decoding fails, fall back to `self.text` (using chardet to make
        # a best guess).
        encoding = guess_json_utf(self.content)
```

So, it seems that it is in general probably better to use `r.json()` than `json.loads(r.text)`.

Answer (score 3):

`.json` is a method of `requests.models.Response` class. It returns json body data from the request's response.

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2')
print(type(r))  # <class 'requests.models.Response'>
r.json()
```

`loads` is a function from `json` package to parse string data

```
import json
print(type(r.text)) # <class 'str'>
json.loads(r.text)
```

`json.loads` can be used with any string data, not only in requests context

```
json.loads('{"key": "value"}')
```

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 slight differences.

1. The **inputs** are different. Assuming `r = requests.get(...)`,

   the `r.json()` outputs type `dict`, but takes in type `requests.models.Response`.

   the `json.loads(r.text)` outputs type `dict`, but takes in type `string`.
2. The **encoding assumptions** are different:

   The `r.json()` goes through additional step to detect the encoding
   before processing the input, more details [here](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/4ea09e49f7d518d365e7c6f7ff6ed9ca70d6ec2e/requests/models.py#L868-L892).

   The `json.loads(r.text)` assumes the default encoding to be 'UTF-8'
   and process the input.

In conclusion, if you are sure the input is 'UTF-8' encoded, use `json.loads(r.text)`. For more a robust way without the need to check for encoding, use `r.json()` (I personally prefer this).

Comment: Which is faster.. Like Does the next line in python waits for the previous line to complete or it runs even before loading into it..

Comment: I guess `json.loads(r.text)` with fixed encoding would be faster; whereas `r.json()` with additional step to check encoding would be more robust!

Answer (score 1):

The `.json()` is a shortcut of `json.loads()`

There is many methods for json in python

`load()`
`loads()`
`dump()`
`dumps()`

Read about difference [here](https://riptutorial.com/python/example/1041/-load--vs--loads----dump--vs--dumps-)