# Replace ASCII HTML characters when loading JSON

Tags: python, html, json, unicode, ascii

I'm loading a JSON file made up of yelp restaurant reviews so that it removes Unicode characters this way:

```
def parse_yelp_restaurant_api(self, response):

        jsonresponse = json.loads(response.text, strict=False)
```

Now I would like to also remove ASCII HTML characters. My JSON file is full of '&#39', '&#34', etc.

Comment: Instead of using `json.loads` you could use `response.json()` as `response.json` also tries to guess encoding of json: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58048879/what-is-the-difference-between-json-method-and-json-loads

Comment: Post an example of the actual input, because you *shouldn't* have to replace anything. Python strings are Unicode, the JSON standard *requires* UTF8, so replacing "Unicode characters" wouldn't leave *any* characters. The code you posted deserializes the JSON into a dictionary, it doesn't remove anything. `response.json()` won't help because it tries to detect the character encoding (UTF8, latin1 etc), not escape sequences. Internally it still calls `json.loads`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The actual input is 'yelp', I'm scraping restaurant reviews (edited the question). The loaded json originally contained sequences like ”\u0041“ but adding ```strict = False``` solved the problem.

Comment: `\u0041` is a valid JSON escape sequence, you don't need `strict = False`. `json.loads('{"banana":[{"x":"O\\u0041Reily"}]}')` returns `{'banana': [{'x': 'OAReily'}]}`. `\u0041` is the plain old ASCII `A`, it didnt' need escaping at all. The HTML entities are *not* valid though and saying this comes from Yelp doesn't make them valid. You'll have to use `html.unescape` on the values to unescape them.

Comment: Instead of dealing with Yelp's customizations yourself why not use a client library like [yelp-python](https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-python) ? You can borrow the way the library deals with Yelp responses too, the [ReponseObject](https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-python/blob/12d611bc2344bbc1c93c83775aa71b7b01b36ad6/yelp/obj/response_object.py#L18) class and Yelp objects like [Business](https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-python/blob/12d611bc2344bbc1c93c83775aa71b7b01b36ad6/yelp/obj/business.py). It iterates over the dictionary returned by `loads` and converts the values based on the field's type.

Comment: You could modify the final attribute assignment to use `html.unescape` or you could leave that step for just the types and attributes that need it. After all I doubt `hours` will contain HTML entities

Comment: Thank you, I ended up using ```response.json()``` as suggested by @puchal and html.unescape removed all the '&#39'-like sequences as suggested by Panagiotis Kanavos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using `html.unescape` on the retrieved fields as suggested by Panagiotis Kanavos.

`response.json()` (as suggested by puchal) also made things easier for unicode guessing.